# How to use entity field type array with multiple different form widgets in symfony2

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony, doctrine

I am looking at an entity called content where I will store data about the content (textfield1, textfield2, bgcolor etc.) in an array inside the entity content (if this is not the best way to go please advice me).

The reason I want to put it in an array instead of just making separate entity fields for it is that I will have different 'content templates' so the amount and type of data fields will be different for each template (and each template of course has its own formbuilder; ContentXType.php, contentYType.php etc.). While one content type might have only one textfield, another might have 10.
I initially started on a design with datafield1, datafield2 etc. but realized that will leave me with a bunch of nullvalues and won't really be pretty =)

At savetime I will generate an html output for this content in a different field called contentRendered.

At edit time I will again want to be able to open up the different datafields from my array in different form widgets, so for example textfield1 in a textfield, textfield2 in a textarea, and bgcolor (the third value of my array) in a colorpicker form widget (I guess I will use a textfield with a jQuery color picker widget).

So my little issue is whether entity type array is the best way to go for this, can I even from within my form builder pick out value 1 from the array and put that in one field, value 2 in a different form field etc.?

Or do I need to go with say a new entity called content_data and use relations?

Or would a better way to go be to define a new entity for each kind of content I plan on using, and then embedding a form for that content type in my main content form?

Comment: You could use Single Table inheritance mapping with doctrine. The table will have null values, but you won't be aware of them, because you'll only work with objects ... http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I will define a new entity for template in which I will specify my templates, and have different twig files for the rendering of each template.
The actual data for each template, which will be of variable amount of fields, will be stored in a serialized array.